# TypeFilter attribute throws NullReferenceException when instanciating inner filter with null argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a simple ASP.NET MVC core filter following [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters), but adding an argument on the filter:

```cs
public class MyFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public ApiAuthorizeAttribute(string arg1 = null) : base(typeof(MyFilterImpl))
    {
        this.Arguments = new object[] { arg1 };
    }

    private class MyFilterImpl : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        private readonly string _arg1;

        public MyFilterImpl(string arg1 /*,  DI dependencies */)
        {
            this._arg1 = arg1;
        }

        async Task IAsyncActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            // Do stuff
            await next();
        }
    }
}
```

This works well when applying the attribute like this:

```cs
[MyFilter(arg1: "foo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
}
```

But it fails when passing null in the attribute declaration:

```cs
[MyFilter] // equivalent to [MyFilter(arg1: null)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
}
```

The runtime throws an `NullReferenceException` on [this line](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/371595962a3c10d870d503269ce1c38f7083e618/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/TypeFilterAttribute.cs#L75). I can work around this by passing `""` instead of null in my case, but is this an expected -or unavoidable- behavior?

Comment: Why have you used `= null`? What are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: `arg1` is an optional parameter for my filter. The filter performs an additional check when `arg1` has a value. I can use `string.Empty` instead, but I'm not sure it's always possible for similar cases, and I think it should be possible to pass any value anyway.

Comment: You have instantiated `this.Arguments` so I would say it is expected behaviour. Either add an `if` clause to not initialize `this.Arguments` if the parameter is `null` or add a second parameterless constructor which does not initialize `this.Arguments`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have instantiated `this.Arguments` in your constructor so I would say it is expected behaviour.

You have a couple of options to fix this.

You can either add an `if` clause to not initialize this.Arguments if the parameter is null

```
public MyFilterAttribute(string arg1 = null) : base(typeof(MyFilterImpl))
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg1))
    {
        this.Arguments = new object[] { arg1 };
    }
}
```

Or add a second parameterless constructor which does not initialize this.Arguments

```
public MyFilterAttribute(string arg1) : base(typeof(MyFilterImpl))
{
    this.Arguments = new object[] { arg1 };
}

public MyFilterAttribute() : base(typeof(MyFilterImpl))
{
}
```

Both will result in the `MyFilterImpl` being instantiated with `null` or the passed in value.

Personally I would favour the second option as it keeps the code cleaner and upholds the Single Responsibility Principle

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than passing `""`, but I still find the behavior of the API counter-intuitive (why can't I pass null if my argument is nullable?). For example, the API should be able to detect the type of the constructor's arguments based on the constructor's signature as a fallback (like it does for dependency injection).

Comment: You should mention that they should be able to receive the parameter in null in the implementation like public class MyFilterImpl : IAsyncActionFilter { DeviceAuthorizationFilterImpl(string arg1 = null) }

Answer (score 1):

As you have found the root cause,

```
if (_factory == null)
{
    var argumentTypes = Arguments?.Select(a => a.GetType())?.ToArray();
    _factory = ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(ImplementationType, argumentTypes ?? Type.EmptyTypes);
}
```

It will initialize argumentTypes with `a.GetType()`, if you pass null or with optionl parameter `null`, this line will throw error expected.

To avoid passing `""` in every action, you could try set `string arg1` with default value `""`.

```
public MyFilterAttribute(string arg1 = "") : base(typeof(MyFilterImpl))
{
    this.Arguments = new object[] { arg1 };
}
```

Comment: `As you have found the root cause,` The OP showed the root cause in their question (`this line`).

Comment: This does't fix the case where I explicitly pass null to the attribute's constructor: `[MyFilter(arg1: null)]`. I ended up using a similar solution though (`this.Arguments = new object[] { arg1 ?? "" };`), but I prefer [Simply Ged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54282785/547733)'s solution as to work around the "bug".